# What is a settings group actually for?

Tags: plugin-development

say i have an option

```
update_option('pp_options', $options);
```

when i want to create a form for that, i learnt that i have to create a settings group

```
register_setting('pp_options_group', 'pp_options');
```

then in the form do

```
settings_fields('pp_options_group')
```

but i dont really what is the settings group actually for? i know its to do with sanitization but why the need to create a group for sanitization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sanitization is secondary function. Main is:

> The [register_setting](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_setting) and [unregister_setting](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/unregister_setting) functions add and remove options from a whitelist of allowed options that the form is able to save. They can also name a sanitize callback function as a security measure to check each option's value. ( [Register settings](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages#Register_Settings) )

Technically `$option_group` argument is used for:

- array key in global array of whitelisted options
- part of filter name to run sanitization callback

Comment: I believe this also adds in the nonces for security, so the plugin developer doesn't have to.